# Using data from 5 different tables on a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need some help on doing multiple Joins, im not very good at this and need a way to get it to work.

There are 5 tables with data and need to get data to output from each table. There is a person, visit, center, date and seenby table. The visit table has ID's to fetch data from other tables. I want to use this table to get the status of the person, to see what date they visited, at what center, their name, and who they were seen by. (i hope this makes sense).

The output should look hopefully like this:

```
> Person FirstName
> Person LastName
> Seen By
> Date
> Center
> Status
```

EDIT// Here is a mockup of what i want to see [image: mockup]

Ive already read up on pivot tables and would prefer not to use that. Ive created a SQL fiddle here: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d19d2c

EDIT//
Ive managed to write half a query but i doubt it works but i guess its a starting point.

```
SELECT d.date
     , p.Firstname
     , p.Lastname
     , c.centername
     , v.status
     , s.FirstName
     , s.LastName
  FROM visit v 
  LEFT 
  JOIN date d 
    ON v.dateID = d.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN centerName c 
    ON c.centerID = c.id
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned getting data, which implies a `SELECT`, but your fiddle shows `INSERT`.  What output are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put the query i tried to do but didnt work

Comment: Check edit. @SableFoste ive described in the question the sort of output i need.

Comment: Could you add some sample lines of what you want to see for a typical row in your report, please? LEFT JOINS will always return a row from the left hand side and you will get blanks if there is no match in the table being joined to it. The default is INNER which will only give you a record if there is a matching record on the table being joined.

Comment: Ive editted with a mockup table of what i want the query to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your table structure it would seem you want a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.date, 
  CONCAT_WS(' ', p.Firstname ,p.Lastname) AS "Person", 
  v.status,
  CONCAT_WS(' ', s.FirstName, s.LastName) AS "Seenby",
  c.centername

FROM visit v 
JOIN person p ON v.PersonID = p.ID
JOIN seenby s ON v.seenbyID = s.ID
LEFT JOIN date d ON v.dateID = d.id 
LEFT JOIN center c ON v.centerID = c.id
```

The last two joins should maybe be normal inner joins and not left joins, adjust as appropriate.

The`CONCAT_WS()`function concatenates its parameters into a string, using the value of the first parameter as separator (a space in this case).

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dab23/7)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i need, but is there a way to join the first and last names together so it just appears in one column? edit// i see u did it haha thanks lots

Comment: @user3411002 Yeah, I just updated the query based on your sample output.